# Sometime SQL Server Select Query is too slow

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table like this which has more than 7 million records:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Test]
(
    [Id] [bigint] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [UUID] [nvarchar](100) NOT NULL,
    [FirstName] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [LastName] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [AddrLine1] [nvarchar](100) NULL,
    [AddrLine2] [nvarchar](100) NULL,
    [City] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [Prov] [nvarchar](10) NULL,
    [Postal] [nvarchar](10) NULL,
    [DateAdded] [datetime] NULL,

    CONSTRAINT [PK_Test] 
        PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Id] ASC)
                    WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, 
                          IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, 
                          ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON, OPTIMIZE_FOR_SEQUENTIAL_KEY = OFF) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

Now, the system runs the following select query everyday during the afternoons. The funny thing is sometimes the same query is so slow which takes about 4 minutes. The second time or other times, same query is pretty fast which takes less than a second.

The query:

```
WITH testquery AS 
(
    SELECT TOP 1 
        'Matched' as location,Firstname, LastName, 
        AddrLine1, AddrLine2, City,  Prov, Postal 
    FROM 
        [Test] 
    WHERE 
        UUID = 'BLABLABLABLABLABLABLABLABLA' 
    ORDER BY 
        DateAdded DESC
),
defaults AS 
(
    SELECT
        'Rejected' AS location, NULL AS Firstname, NULL AS LastName, 
        NULL AS AddrLine1, NULL AS AddrLine2, NULL AS City, NULL AS Prov, 
        NULL AS Postal 
)
SELECT * 
FROM testquery

UNION ALL

SELECT * 
FROM defaults
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM testquery);
```

Can somebody help please?

**Notes:**

- I have a service which adds around 1000 new records to the table everyday in the mornings.
- [avg_fragmentation_in_percent] is 0.01
- UUID can be duplicated if I have the same person with different addresses.
- The table is not used somewhere else at the same time.
- Database is not busy with other queries at the same time. I checked using "sys.dm_exec_requests"

Comment: Look at the actual query plan.  Does it suggest any missing indexes?  Perhaps on (UUID,DateAdded) so the table doesn't have to scanned every time.  Also consider loading a temp table with the results of `testquery` so you don't run it twice.

Comment: You don't have an index that covers ***either*** of your search terms; `UUID, DateAdded`...  This means that the query has to scan all 7 million records for the matching `UUID`, then sort the results by `DateAdded` so that it can return the single record you're looking for.  That's like me asking you to tell me what line number the word `either` appears on all the pages of a book, then pick the page where that line number is the highest.  Adding an index on `test(UUID, DateAdded DESC)` will make inserts *slightly* slower, and make this query *much* faster.

Comment: Thanks. However, It didn't help, because I tired this Test(UUID, DateAdded desc). It terminated it because a duplicate key was found. Any other suggestions please?

Answer (score 2):

The usual explanation for this is a cold cache.  In your case, I think the issue would be the `ORDER BY` in the first CTE.

To fix this problem, you want an index on `test(UUID, DateAdded desc)`.

I'm not sure why this would speed up after the first execution.  Perhaps the server's caches are working particularly well.

Comment: Thanks. However, It didn't help, because I tired this Test(UUID, DateAdded desc). It terminated it because a duplicate key was found. Any other suggestions please?

Comment: @Ribaz . . . An index allows duplicates.  You are either defining a unique index/constraint or a foreign key constraint.

Answer (score 2):

**You need a good index to service this query efficiently.**

You say that you can't create one because of duplicate key errors: there is no need for an index to be unique.

So the one you're looking for will depend on what other queries you are running, but the following will suffice for this query:

```sql
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX IX_Test_UuidDate ON
    Test (UUID ASC, DateAdded DESC)
    INCLUDE (Firstname, LastName, AddrLine1, AddrLine2, City, Prov, Postal)

GO
```

---

**Furthermore, there is no need to query the table twice.**

Start with a dummy `VALUES` table constructor so you always have a row, then `LEFT JOIN` the table and use `CASE` to deal with not having a row.

```sql
WITH testquery AS 
(
    SELECT TOP 1 
        *
    FROM 
        [Test] 
    WHERE 
        UUID = 'BLABLABLABLABLABLABLABLABLA' 
    ORDER BY 
        DateAdded DESC
)
SELECT
    CASE WHEN UUID IS NULL 'Rejected' ELSE 'Matched' END as location,
    t.Firstname,
    t.LastName,
    t.AddrLine1,
    t.AddrLine2,
    t.City,
    t.Prov,
    t.Postal 
FROM (VALUES(0)) AS v(dummy)
LEFT JOIN testquery AS t ON 1=1;
```